# Erro ao compilar REACT

Tags: react, react-native, reactive-programming

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro em meu terminal ao tentar compilar o react

> `./src/pages/main/index.js Line 3:  'api' is defined but never used  no-unused-var`

Segue o código:

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
const api = axios.create({ 
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
}); 
export default api;
```

Comment: É erro ou warning?

Comment: Compiled with warnings.

./src/pages/main/index.js
  Line 3:  'api' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

Comment: Um warning, me desculpe.

Comment: O problema é que ele não inicializa o servidor.

Comment: Mas ele dá build failed?

Comment: Não vejo problema no seu código, como vc está usando no import? Para seu metro bundler, verifica seu código e start tudo novamente.

Comment: Isso é um warning, não é erro.

Comment: Onde você está chamando a variável `api` ? O warning diz que ela está definida mas nunca é chamada.

Answer (score 1):

Vejo que você criou um componente API e possivelmente deve ter importado ele no arquivo Main (é o que deveria ser feito). Porém você não está chamando o import da API no seu Main.
Algo tipo assim:

```
main.js
...
import api from '../caminho/api' 
...
```

Porém você não deve ter chamado ela em algum lugar do Main. Ai não faz a requisição e o import do Main fica dando Warning.